# Unable to construct Document object from xml string

Tags: java, xml, xpath, xml-parsing

I have xml string coming to my appliaction like follows

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?><loc:getLocation xmlns:loc="http://www.csapi.org/schema/parlayx/terminal_location/v2_3/local">
     <loc:address>tel:+919420161525</loc:address>
     <loc:requestedAccuracy>500</loc:requestedAccuracy>
     <loc:acceptableAccuracy>500</loc:acceptableAccuracy>
  </loc:getLocation>
```

I want to construct Document object from this so that using XPath, I can retrieve required data. I tried following code

```
    DocumentBuilderFactory factory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();  
    DocumentBuilder builder;  
    Document document;
    try  
    {  
        builder = factory.newDocumentBuilder();  
        document = builder.parse( new InputSource( new StringReader( header.concat(str) ) ) );  
    } catch (Exception e) {  
        e.printStackTrace();  
    }
```

But I get Document object as null. I don;t get any exception. I tried validating my XML online http://www.xmlvalidation.com/ I dont see any errors.

Any idea what I am doing wrong ?

Comment: what's header? What's the result of header.concat(str)? If the XML is valid, why are you adding something at the start?

Comment: Also note that this xml is a namespaced one which means you probably will need to implement the namespace context, too.

Comment: JP Moresmau, Sorry for confusion,  'header' is not there.  Its new StringReader(str), where str is xml string that i am mentioning.   Arthur, I dint get you, can you please elaborate ?

Comment: When you say you "get document object as null" how are you determining this? If there's no exception then the value of the `document` variable will _not_ be Java `null`, but the toString representation of a non-null `Document` DOM node (i.e. what you would get from `System.out.println(document)`) is a string like `"[#document:null]"`

Comment: Correct Ian. So that means Document has not got formed right ? if I go to access address using xpath like  xPath.evaluate("//loc:address/text()", document);  I get address as null

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As Arthur Elrich pointed out in the comments, you should make the factory namespace aware and provide a namespace context to the XPath instance.

```
DocumentBuilderFactory factory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
factory.setNamespaceAware(true);
DocumentBuilder builder = factory.newDocumentBuilder();  
Document document = builder.parse( new InputSource(new StringReader(...)));

XPath xpath = XPathFactory.newInstance().newXPath();
xpath.setNamespaceContext(new MyNamespaceContext());
String s = xpath.evaluate("//location:address/text()", document);
System.out.println(s2);
```

And a simplistic `NamespaceContext` implementation:

```
static class MyNamespaceContext implements NamespaceContext {

    @Override
    public String getNamespaceURI(String prefix) {
        switch (prefix) {
        case "location":
            return "http://www.csapi.org/schema/parlayx/terminal_location/v2_3/local";
        }
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public String getPrefix(String namespaceURI) {
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public Iterator getPrefixes(String namespaceURI) {
        return null;
    }

}
```

Note that the prefix used in the XPath expression is different from the prefix used in the document. They can of course be identical, but this example shows that what matters is the namespace URI, not the prefix.

As an alternative, you can get away with not being namespace aware by using the `local-name`function:

```
xpath.evaluate("//*[local-name() = 'address']/text()", document);
```

However, this alternative is a lot less robust, since it will retrive all elements named `address`, regardless of their actual namespaces.

Comment: Thanks Forty, I got it working by some other way. However your solution too works. Cheers.